# A suggest to solve QLineEdit property

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I'm working with Qt5...and I'm tryng to set a default value in QLineEdit in case of I wrote nothing in the linetext area.
Is possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for example by connecting

```
 void QLineEdit::editingFinished () [signal]
```

and check in the slot actual text from `QLineEdit` and if necessary set yours.

Answer (score 1):

### If you want user to have empty field when they start editing

First use [`placeHolderText` property of `QLineEdit`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) to set the default value to display.

Then connect [`editingFinished`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) (or possibly some [other](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlineedit.html#signals), check them out) signal to your own slot, where you check if text is empty (and then use the `placeHolderText` value) or if user entered something.

### If you want to leave default text for user to edit

Instead of using `placeHolderText`, simply set contents of the `QLineEdit` to desired default value, when you create it. Then in the slot for `editingFinished`, if user made field empty, restore the text to default.